# Get all keys in hash with same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get all the keys with the same value from a hash and put them into an array as separate entries. I have this line of code but it sends everything in as a single entry:

```
@highest_wf_words << h.select {|k, v| v == val}.keys
```

can anyone advise how to separate the keys so I end up with [["a"],["b"],["c"]] instead of [["a","b","c"]],

Comment: can you provide a sample data for `h`?

Comment: Your question is (sic) "how one can get all keys with the same value?", but your code suggests that it should be, "how one can get all keys with a specified value?" Those are different questions.

Comment: Sorry Cary you are right. The way the data is entered is a bit backwards. I'm very new to Ruby (this is my first week working with the language so just bear with me for now :) thanks for your response and advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
h.select {|k, v| v == val}.keys.each {|k| @highest_wf_words << [k]}
```

Or this:

```
@highest_wf_words.concat(h.select {|k, v| v == val}.keys.map {|k| [k]})
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you construct a hash rather than an array.

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, d: 3, e: 2 }

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| (g[v] ||= []) << k }
  #=> {1=>[:a, :c], 2=>[:b, :e], 3=>[:d]}
```

This answers the question posed by the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, yet simpler:

```
h.select { |k,v| v == h.values.max }.keys
```

For example,

```
h = { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 2 }
# implement the above solution
h.select { |k,v| v == h.values.max }.keys
    #=> ["b", "c"]
```

Hopefully, that's what you'd want! :)

Comment: Can you explain further? It's not clear to me how "max" is involved if the goal is to find equal values, not greatest values.